# Sorting csv file based on two columns in unix

Tags: linux, csv, sorting, unix, awk

I'm a beginner in unix shell scripting. I'm trying to sort a csv file based on two columns.

My file looks like below:

```
sh-4.4$ cat test.csv                                                             
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115                                        
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115                                                 
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215                                                
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215                                                 
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117                                                 
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117
```

I want to group by the 3rd column and the 2nd column should also be ordered as shown below:

```
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215
```

I tried doing `sort -t',' -k3 -k2 test.csv`. This does groups the column 3, but it does not sort the column 2. Its output looks like below.

```
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115                                             
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115              
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117                 
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117                 
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215                 
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215
```

I also tried `sort -t',' -k3 -rk2 test.csv`. This however sorts the column 2 as I desired but the column 3 is not sorted as I expected. Its output looks like below.

```
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215                                                                                                          
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215                                                                                                          
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117                                                                                                          
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117                                                                                                          
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115                                                                                                          
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. Suggestions to sort using awk is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

restrict the sorting fields

```
$ sort -t, -k3,3 -k2,2 file
```

should do.

Note however that the output you want doesn't match the spec you describe.  You'll get

```
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215
```

grouped by third field only and sorted by second field.

Perhaps this is what you wanted?

```
$ sort -t, -k3 -k2,2r file

603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215
```

note that `-k3` means starting from 3rd field to the end, which seems what you want based on the order of the last fields.  Also, you want to reorder the rows based on 2nd field in reverse order.

**NB.**  If your numerical fields are not zero padded you may want to add `-n` option indicate numerical ordering instead of lexical ordering.  Here it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Sorry my spec was confusing. I basically want my output as shown above.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. This did work fine when I tried at an online unix terminal for testing. But unfortunately it is not working in my unix terminal which is on SunOs. I doubt whether this command is not working because SunOs!

Comment: When I run the command, I get output only like this: :(  603,02,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131115
603,02,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,20,0123456,1111,201806131117
603,02,9876542,2222,201806131215
603,20,9876542,2222,201806131215

Answer (score 1):

Sort will work sorting data on csv & txt file , it will print the output on console

-t says columns are delimited by '|' , -k1 -k2 says that-- it will sort te data by column 1 & then by 2

```
$ sort -t '|' -k1 -k2 <INPUT_FILE>
```

For storing the result in output file use following command

```
$ sort -t '|' -k1 -k2 <INPUT_FILE> -o <OUTPUTFILE>
```

If you wann do it with ignoring header line then use following command

```
(head -n1 INPUT_FILE && sort <(tail -n+2 INPUT_FILE)) > OUTPUT_FILE
```

head -n1 INPUT_FILE which will print only the first line of your file i.e. header

&
This special **tail** syntax gets your file from second line up to EOF.